# Deleting an Azure Functionapp and its associated Storage Account using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I have several Azure Function app services that I need to remove along with their associated Storage accounts. Each function has its own storage account that is only used by that function. I have used a PowerShell command which deleted the function but it leaves behind the storage account. Is there a way to use PowerShell to querying the function first to get its storage account name so I can then use a similar command to delete the account?

Here is the PowerShell command I used to delete the Function:

```
Remove-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "myResGrp" -Name "myFuncName"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the connection string for the storage account that is stored in [`AzureWebJobsStorage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage) application setting, e.g. :

```
# Untested demonstration code, use with caution.
function Remove-FunctionAppAndStorageAccount
{
    param
    (
        $ResourceGroupName,
        $FunctionName
    )

    # Retrieve the function app
    $app = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionName;

    # Grab the AzureWebJobsStorage app setting
    $azureWebJobsStorageSetting = $app.SiteConfig.AppSettings | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "AzureWebJobsStorage" };

    # Parse the storage account name
    $accountNamePart = ($azureWebJobsStorageSetting.Value -split ";" | Where-Object { $_ -like "AccountName*" });
    $storageAccountName = ($accountNamePart -split "=")[1]

    # Remove the app
    Remove-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionName;

    # Remove the storage account
    Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName;
}    

# Remove both function app and storage account in one line
Remove-FunctionAppAndStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "myResGrp" -FunctionName "myFuncName"
```